# How to hide the dependencies' function names in shared library?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, reverse-engineering, debug-symbols

I'm buiding a shared library on Linux, which reference to other library like `boost`, `CryptoPP`, `jsoncpp`. The problem is the final .so file contains function names, in *IDA Pro*:

[image]

I thought it's because linking to dynamic library, so I build `boost` static library, but `boost` function names still visible.

I tried **strip** the .so file:

```
strip my.so
strip --strip-unneeded -x my.so
```

Still no luck.

Some competitors may reverse engineer my library, how to hide these function names to make it more difficult to crack?

Answer (score 2):

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL, -Wl,--gc-sections
```

Comment: This answer could be explained by providing a bit more explanation of how/why it solves the problem / addresses the asker's concerns about cracking.

Answer (score 0):

You should

- compile with `-fvisibility=hidden` (functions which are actually exported should be marked with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` in code
- link against static versions of external libraries (by using `-l:libXYZ.a` syntax in `LDFLAGS`); of course they need to be present on your system.

Comment: I tried build and link to `boost` static libraries, there is no *libboost....so* in the output of `ldd my.so`,  but the names still exist in IDA.